# Always focusing on Tab Container when the page was postback

Tags: asp.net, tabcontrol, autopostback

What should I do to prevent my page to focus on tab container in every postback?

example: when my checkbox was set to **Autopostback = "true"**, when I click that checkbox, it will postback but it will focus on tab container..

the other page that has no tab container even though I have a field there that is set to autopostback="true" does not have that kind of problem...

I think, there is something that I need to do to remove the focus on tab container when the page was postback... but I don't know what is that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having focus on other control in your page after the event with autopostback, for example `Button1.Focus();` place last in the line of the method